# Searching for keyword in file content located in a folder

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to produce a batch script that will locate some text inside of a .txt file. The folder contains hundreds of these txt files and need a script to split them. If the file contains the phrase
`Initialisation Failed` then I would like to store that .txt in another folder. If not then just leave it in the current folder.

Below I have an attempt that I used, but this would only work on a single file.

```batch-file
findstr/mc:"Initialisation Failed"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /mc:"Initialisation Failed" *.txt') do move "%%a" "T:\Jack Lythgoe\Production Test\InitialisaionError_Review\batch test\error"
```

**Expected Output** - error (folder)

```
log223.txt
log24324.txt
log546.txt
log234.txt
```

Once the script has run, the files containing Initialisation failed should be transferred into error folder which is in that directory.

Error output from cmd

```html
for /F "delims=" %a in ('findstr /mc:"Initialisation Failed" *.txt') do move "%a" "T:\Jack Lythgoe\Production Test\InitialisaionError_Review\batch test\error"
FINDSTR: Cannot open *.txt
```

Comment: `findstr "Hello World"` matches lines that contain `Hello` and/or `World`. Use `findstr /mc:"Initialisation Failed" or `find`, which does handle the searchstring literally.

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /mc:"Initialisation Failed" *.txt') do ECHO moving %%a`

Comment: How can i move the files with this to a different folder?

Comment: replace the part after `do` with `move "%%a" "D:\estination folder\"`

Comment: T:\Jack Lythgoe\Production Test\InitialisaionError_Review\batch test>findstr/mc:"Initialisation Failed". That is what i get in cmd. My code is in the edit snippet

Comment: Your snipped works fine. All matching files in the current working folder get moved.

Comment: Nah, i run the script and it produces the first line. Nothing happens and the cmd window stays open

Comment: Remove the first line. You don't need it, and it's incomplete (waiting for text to parse). The `for` loop parses the output of the command in parentheses, so all you need is the `for` line.

Comment: Script run this time, but nothing got transferred over.

Comment: can you please copy/paste your exact output to your question?

Comment: Please let me know if you need me to elaborate anymore :)

Comment: Your actual output would be helpful. As far as I can determine, the line should work as intended.

Comment: As in what is in the log file?

Comment: As in what's on your screen. Your code doesn't create a logfile.

Comment: a folder is located in that directory named "error". The batch script should go through all of the log files, and where there is the string "Initialisation Failed", that file should be moved to the "error" folder. Currently when the script is run, nothing changes/gets moved.

Comment: Yes, you already said that. Maybe there is nothing to move? What does `findstr /mc:"Initialisation Failed" *.txt` say?

Comment: It doesnt say anything, cmd window disapears instantly.

Comment: Well if your code you suggested is right then there should be something to move lol.

Comment: Don't run a batchfile with a doubleclick (especially for troubleshooting). Open `cmd` window and run it manually from there. The code I suggested does work for me. If it doesn't for you, there is something wrong, which I can't guess without seeing your results.

Comment: "for /F "delims=" %a in ('findstr /mc:"Initialisation Failed" *.txt') do move "%a" "T:\Jack Lythgoe\Production Test\InitialisaionError_Review\batch test\error"
FINDSTR: Cannot open *.txt" This is the error i recieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code @Stephan told me to use was to complicated. I had now just used my brain a bit and figured it out myself. This code block will search within the files of the current directory and subdirectories and find the exact match of the string in the .log files, and store the name of the file in results.csv. If any errors it will say no match found

```html
@echo off
findstr /s /m /c:"INITIALISATION FAILED-32775" *.log > results.csv
if %errorlevel%==0 (
echo Found! logged files into results.txt
) else (
echo No matches found
)
```